# Form OnClick event handler - How to overlap other event handlers?

Tags: delphi

I'm having a little trouble writing a validation function to my Form.

I have a GroupBox within my Form, on this GroupBox a couple buttons, and a StatusBar at the bottom of this Form. I've written a function to display the validation messages in a StatusBar panel. I have a Timer and the messages are visible in the StatusBar for five seconds, like a hint to the user.

But I would like that if before the message disappears for itself the user happen to click at any object within the Form (GroupBox, Panel, Button... anywhere), that i could use the form OnClick to clear the validation message.

I don't want to work with every control possible to interact, clearing the message if the control was clicked. I want to do this only one time at the Form OnClick, however, the objects OnClick event handler override the parent (Form) OnClick event handler.

I don't know if i was clear enough, but is there any way i could do this? Writing code just one time to every click within the form?

Thank you in advance, and sorry for my English and any orthographic or grammatical mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `TApplicationEvents` component to your form. And implement a handler for its `OnMessage` event like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; 
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message=WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
    ClearStatusBarMessage;
end;
```

where `ClearStatusBarMessage` is your code to clear the hint.

This event handler will get called every time the application processes a queued event on the main UI thread. So, this may be more far-reaching than you might imagine. I'm not sure exactly how your application is designed, but you may need to tweak the code a little to get the exact behaviour that you desire.

Comment: Does `Handled` default to False then?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Indeed it does. If it did not it would be very annoying.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It worked perfectly. Thank you for taking a little of your time to help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Marcus gives generally sound advice there. There are lots of ways in which you could tweak this code to be more discerning. You may not need to mind you. Especially if the form is modal. However, comparing `Msg.hwnd` against the form's handle may not do what you expect. Many messages will be dispatched to children of the form and not the form itself.

Comment: You're right. I should have just provided a caveat: if you left-click on anything in the application, including other forms, this method will be called.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I added such a caveat to the answer. Thanks for the prompt.

Comment: As my form is modal I will not have problem with the user interacting with other forms. And even if he does (no matter with what mouse button) it will be fine, as it shows that the user its moving on with his business, ignoring the message. But I'm glad for this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to solve a similar problem.. I handled the form event

```
OnMouseActivate
```

Copy&Paste from the help:

> Occurs when the user presses a mouse button with the mouse pointer over a control and the parent form is not active.

I use Delphi 2007